# Get the text of the clicked link using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the value of the clicked link?

This is my html:

```
<div id="results">
   <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="">1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="">2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I attempted to get the value:

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function (){
   var text = $(this).innerHTML;
});
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to call a native DOM property on a jQuery element.

Use `html()` or `text()`  if you use the jquery element, not `innerHTML`, or use `this.innerHTML` :

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function (){
   var text = this.innerHTML;
});
```

Using `text()` would clean the string from the HTML artifacts, so it's probably what you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function (){
   var text = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following.

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function (){
   var text = $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: Pretty foolish of me lol. Thanks. Marking you correct because you were the first to answer :)

Comment: @dystroy check the time it was answered

Comment: @Dumisani double-check the time it was answered

Comment: @dystroy :answered 18 mins ago, Dangling Pointer :answered 16 mins ago.

Comment: Lol are we really going to argue about times? Come on now